# Hyponymy and hypernymy for adjectives

Tags: lexical-semantics, adjectives

Would the concepts of hyponymy and hypernymy be used for adjectives? Hyponymy and hypernymy are usually used for nouns. And for verbs the WordNet people have created the concept *troponymy* for a manner kind of hyponymy and hypernymy.

In Danish, there are *nybarberet* (newly shaved) and *glatbarberet* (clean shaven) which could have a relation to the "hypernym" *barberet* (shaved/shaven). Should we say that the hypernym of *nybarberet* is *barberet* or are there other ways to model the relationship or refer to the relationship?

Comment: I see no reason why these semantic concepts should be restricted to specific word classes. They could equally well apply to verbs, for example: _ingest_ could be a hyperonym of _drink_ and _eat_.

Comment: And certainly such ontological classification is common, like this classification of [English verbs of cutting](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf) from a lexical semantics class.